# Changing language on ID3 lyrics

Tags: software-recommendation, language, id3-tag

eyeD3 has an add-lyrics option that takes arguments Lyrics, Description, Language.  Lyrics is supposed to be a filename, description a string, and language the three character code from ISO3166-2.  If all three are present, they are delimited by **:** (colon).

Unfortunately, in MacOS zsh, the colon and the next word are treated as part of the filename, which means "file not found."  Putting quotes around the filename causes eyeD3 to fail with a Usage message.

Is there a way to change the language tag without also resetting the lyrics?  If I omit it, the default is "eng."  I can still read the lyrics, so it's not a big deal, but it bugs me to have them all tagged "eng" when some are dut, ita, ell, por, spa, etc.

Typical invocation:

```
eyeD3 --encoding utf8 --add-lyrics Lyrics.txt \
                                   filename.mp3 > /dev/null
```

/dev/null redirect is because eyeD3 will list all tags (including lyrics) whether it changed them or not.  That is of course, quite long, but the issue is can be illustrated by a small part:

```
Lyrics: [Description: ] [Lang: eng]
Dit is de boodschap die Jeremia van de Here kreeg op het
```

Now, according to the documentation, the way to fix that "eng" is to use

```
eyeD3 --encoding utf8 --add-lyrics Lyrics.txt:The Description:dut \
                                   filename.mp3 > /dev/null
```

which, as I said, complains that there is no file named Lyrics.txt:The  Escaping the colon (`… Lyrics.txt:The …`) did not change anything.  Quoting the file name made it worse (usage message).

Comment: Please add an example of how you use/call the tool ne what the output is.

Comment: Unfortunately you didn’t copy/paste the full Terminal output including the error message. But it seems as if the command complains about not finding a file called `Lyrics.txt:The` (which obviously doesn‘t exist), not about the colon as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem is "too many variables."

There is apparently no way to just change the language tag¹ without adding lyrics.  So:

First, if there are (or may be) already lyrics in the file, you have to remove them, because `--add-lyrics` will do what it says: *add* to the lyrics already there.  So

```
eyeD3  --remove-all-lyrics  (audio-file)
```

Second, if you want to include a language, you must also have a description (but it can be blank).

```
eyeD3  --add-lyrics  (lyrics-file)::dut  (audio-file)
```

Third, the lyrics file name must not depend on globbing.  The shell will try to glob the entire string up to the first white space.  So the shell (not eyeD3) will complain that there are no matches for `lyrics*.txt::dut` (for example).  So if you need to use wild cards:

```
LYRICS="lyrics*.txt"
eyeD3  --add-lyrics  $LYRICS::dut  (audio-file)
```

Fourth, the third example still doesn't work!  The shell will expand the variable in quotes but will not apply globbing.  It will be as if the asterisks were escaped.  So:

```
LYRICS="$(ls lyrics*.txt)"
eyeD3  --add-lyrics  $LYRICS::dut  (audio-file)
```

Finally, if you try to add a description that contains any white space, `eyeD3` will try to use whatever comes after the first white space as the target audio file.  To avoid that, use quotes:

```
eyeD3  --add-lyrics  "$LYRICS:Dutch lyrics:dut"  (audio-file)
```

But not single-quotes, because that prevents expansion of the `$LYRICS`.

¹A fiie can contain more than one set of lyrics and `eyeD3` is able to remove one, finding it by description.  So, if each had a different description, it should be possible to modify the python code to change the language code on the lyric that has a particular description.  Or to find the lyric that contains a search string and change the LANG on that.

Comment: I have a hard time seeing this as an answer to your question, most likely some details are missing in the question. Maybe an edit of both would make it clearer (as well as focusing the answer on just the solution, without listing the things which didn't work).

Comment: It's not an answer to "changing lang without re-adding lyrics" since that (as far as I know) isn't possible.  It IS an answer to "get the correct language on lyrics." which is been better.  Since it took me quite a while to figure out all the multiple issues making it difficult, I think it worthwhile to explain them all for the next victim.

Answer (score 0):

As with any utility called from a shell, arguments which include characters with special meaning to the shell need to be quoted (`'` or `"`)  or escaped (`\`).

```
eyeD3 --encoding utf8 --add-lyrics 'Lyrics.txt:The Description:dut' \
                                   filename.mp3 > /dev/null
```

At least according to the explanations in `eyeD3 --help` you can also run

```
eyeD3 --encoding utf8 --add-lyrics 'Lyrics.txt::dut' filename.mp3 > /dev/null
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that escaping the colon did not change anything.  I did mention that quoting made it worse.  eyeD3 is open source, so I'll examine the code to see whether it's possible to change the lang on the lyrics without changing the lyrics themselves.

Comment: @wgroleau did you try the commands from my answer?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned the documentation, which as far as I can tell is only available from `eyeD3 --help` and tried several variations.  Omitting description only adds the rest of the non-whites-space to the filename.  But if it worked, it would be acceptable, though I would prefer to not have to re-add the lyrics at the same time.